# Can Dream Portals spawn on other side boards

Tags: eldritch-horror

Can [Dream Portals](https://eldritchhorror.fandom.com/wiki/Dream_Portal) spawn on other side boards?

The dreamlands rules state:

> 5. Spawn Dream Portals
>
> Reveal Gates from the top of the Gate stack until three Gates are revealed that each correspond to **a space that is not on the Dreamlands side board**. Place the three Dream Portal tokens on those spaces. Leave each revealed Gate in the Gate stack and do not randomize the Gate stack after spawning a Dream Portal.

The rules doesn't state anything about in which order side boards should be setup. It just says to spawn the Dream Portals during step 5 of the Dreamlands side board setup.

So I assume they can. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you play with a sideboard only if a Prelude Card or Ancient One requires it. Some Preludes call for specific sideboards, and some Ancient Ones specifically require certain sideboards to be playable. If you want to use multiple sideboards, you could either house rule it so that Dream Portals only spawn on the main map or spawn on any other sideboard. Do note that some sideboards also come with their own special setup rules as well.

There are no rules that explicitly state that Dream Portals wouldn't spawn on the other sideboard, so your assumption is correct. I suspect that playing with multiple sideboards will greatly increase the difficulty as investigators have more ground to cover.